# How to fix Superset Create admin account error

Tags: python-3.x, apache-superset

I was trying to set up Superset on WIN10, everything is ok after I run:" **fabmanager create-admin --app superset**" (to create admin account) 
it reports:'fabmanager' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
any ideal how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you tried to set it up, and have you installed Flask, and do you use virtualenv?

First:

`pip install -U Flask` or if you use Python3 `pip3 install -U flask`

Then:

```
set FLASK_APP=superset
flask fab create-admin
```

Also - you have a nice tutorial here on how to do it -> https://gist.github.com/mark05e/d9cccae129dd11a21d7219eddd7d9923